# Static inline functions are greatly preferred over macros. What does this mean?

Tags: c

> Static inline functions are greatly preferred over macros. They
>   provide type safety.

What does this mean? Can anybody explain and if possible provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that it's better to do (in a header):

```
static inline int max(int a, int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

than

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Since the former has its parameters declared as being `int`, along with the result

<sup>(so your C compiler would complain clearly if you code `max(3.14, "pi")`, but if you used a macro, the error would be more cryptic or unnoticed)</sup>

Functions are at a higher level than macros, which are just dumb text replacement.

Since the function is `static`, it won't be visible outside the C file that `#include`s the header its in, so there won't be any "symbol re-defined" clashes when you link together several C files using this.

Comment: Note: there is a `;` after the #define.

Comment: @joop Thanks. That was of course a typo, rather harmless but it really shouldn't be there. We can't waste semicolons or we might run out.

Comment: But the classic semicolon slip is actually yet another reason why you should use functions over macros; C programmers are known to write semicolons everywhere;